# Можно ли вкладывать .container в свой контейнер?

Tags: html, bootstrap

В таком случае бутстраповский контейнер выступает контейнером контента, а мой - контейнером родителем - максимальной шириной сайта.

**На примере:**

Есть макет шириной в `800px`, сам контент внутри - `590px` (была изменена максимальная ширина `мedium-контейнера`).

```
<div class="my-container">  <!-- 800px -->  
  <div class="container"> <!-- 590px -->  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Почему так:**
Секции имеют свой `background`, `border`.

**Ключевой вопрос:** можно ли так делать или это плохая практика?

Comment: Вы конечно можете, но это будет ошибкой.

Comment: почему это будет ошибкой?

Comment: Можно .........., но лучше использовать ширину колонок, т.е. например: `.container > .row.justify-content-center > .col-6 `

Comment: А если, например, необходимо добавить каждой отдельной секции свой background и border? Как удобнее всего это сделать? <div class="container border">?

Comment: Делать вы можете как угодно, главное, чтобы вы достигли поставленной цели. Если вас все устраивает, то значит можно так делать. Уж поверьте, что когда придет время переделывать, то придется переделывать все полностью ;-)